# Send Mail in ASP .NET (SMTP)

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

I wrote the following code in my code file. But it does not work... plz help me! :)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MailMessage msgeme = new MailMessage("someone@example.com", "someone@example.com", "subject", "body");
    SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
    smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpclient.Send(msgeme);
    smtpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someone@example.com", "password");


}
```

I tried both 587 and 465. Bt it shows SMTP Exception handler error. Can anyone help???

Comment: I don't know if its the cause of your problem but don't you want to set the credentials before you send the mail?

Comment: 587 is the correct port. @Robotsushi is also correct, you need to set the credentials prior to sending.

Comment: Check to see if you have a firewall or anti-virus blocking that port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add DeliveryMethod with the different enumerations, and also credentials before send:

```
MailMessage msgeme = new MailMessage("someone@example.com", "someone@example.com", "subject", "body");
SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someone@example.com", "password");
smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

smtpclient.Send(msgeme);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your credentials before you call the send method. 
More information about the error would be helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 MailMessage msgeme = new MailMessage("someone@example.com", "someone@example.com", "subject", "body");
 SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
 smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
 smtpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someone@example.com", "password");
 smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 smtpclient.Send(msgeme);
```

Work !!! Thank you