# Sending mail from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Is there a way to send mail from an asp.net application? Right now I'm trying to figure out how to create confirmation emails when you sign up for a service.

Comment: Did you look at any of the related questions already in SO about this?

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage message=new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
message.From="from e-mail";
message.To="to e-mail";
message.Subject="Message Subject";
message.Body="Message Body";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer="SMTP Server Address";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

Comment: I thought these were deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [SmtpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).  For example code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333268/send-mail-in-asp-net-smtp/6333333#6333333) from Shlomi.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the followin link it goes into depth of hwo to send mail from Asp.net:

http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-csharp-to-send-an-e-mail-through-smtp/

Answer (score 1):

this code will get you started 
    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
                {

```
                mm.From = new MailAddress("noreply@mail.com");

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");

                string smtpServerUserName = "username";
                string smtpServerPassword = "password"; 
            if (smtpServerUserName.HasValue() && smtpServerPassword.HasValue())
                {
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpServerUserName, smtpServerPassword);
                }
                smtpServerPort = "";
                if (smtpServerPort.HasValue())
                {
                    client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(smtpServerPort, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                mm.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

                mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

                mm.Subject = subject;
                mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("you@home.com"));
                mm.Body = body;

                client.Send(mm);
            }
        }
```

where hasvalue() is just a extensionmethod which inverts string.IsNullOrEmpty()

you can use papercut (http://papercut.codeplex.com/) to test it on your local pc, then use 127.0.0.1 as ipaddress without any smtpusername, password or portnumber.

```
/// <summary>
    /// checks if a string is null or empty (hasvalue = false if null or empty)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool HasValue(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/163829/sending-an-email-in-c-with-or-without-attachments) generic guide on sending emails in .NET: